# Grammar of the current version of the C# language

Tags: c#, syntax

Where is the grammar of the current version of the C# language?

I mean a grammar similar to this SQL grammar: [https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20210130010947/https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html)

I would like to check, for example, what is the `complex_pattern` element mentioned on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching page and how it relates to the `pattern` and `primary_pattern` grammar elements defined on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3 page. Where can I find it in the grammar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most recent version of C# with a (draft) specification is C# 6.0. There's a grammar interspersed in [the specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction).

More recent versions of C# don't have a specification yet (you have to take the C# 6.0 specification, and add in proposals from features present in later versions, [e.g. here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/)).

The Roslyn repository contains a generated grammar from the most recent version of the compiler, [currently here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/6c7e5b2437b149e8d8ca42aa5e79e721060b3dae/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Generated/CSharp.Generated.g4). Search the Roslyn repository for [`path:**/*.g4`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Froslyn+path%3A**%2F*.g4&type=code) if it moves.